# converting a huge html file to php variable/echo

Tags: php, html, variables, echo

I have an enormous file of HTML that I'd like to convert to one variable for output. So, something like:

```
<div class="section">
    <h3>hey<? echo $anothervar ?></h3>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />
</div>
```

to

```
$myvar;

    $myvar="<div class=\"section\">
                <h3>hey" . $anothervar . "</h3>";
    $myvar.=            "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" class=\"button\" />
            </div>";
```

ryv.  except its a HUGE file, with PHP peppered in there, but I need to get it all in one variable to pass it and then return it. Is there an automated way to do this (hopefully on windows with something like NP++?) or at least a way to automate a good portion of this rather than taking me hours and hours of going through the lines?

EDIT: Everyone is debating why I want to do that. Here's the quick and perhaps boring response; I'm writing a plugin for WordPress that takes a shortcode and replaces it with the output of a single variable; if one just echoes (as it is done in the file I was given) then WP puts the shortcode output in a different place relative to the content. So, yes, you may not want to do this but that's the reason  (http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Overview):

> When the_content is displayed, the
>   shortcode API will parse any
>   registered shortcodes such as
>   "[my-shortcode]", separate and parse
>   the attributes and content, if any,
>   and pass them the corresponding
>   shortcode handler function. Any string
>   returned (not echoed) by the shortcode
>   handler will be inserted into the post
>   body in place of the shortcode itself.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: `PHP peppered in there`... Have you considered `include`?

Comment: I *would* say you could use an (xml/regex) parser, but that would require your inputs to actually be properly formatted and valid.  Garbage in, garbage out as they say.

You can't have variables held inside a string that is a variable. Once the parser hit the variables, it will either get the value, or simple store the variable's symbol (name) in its place.

Comment: yes, why not just include() the file? this would process the PHP code inside and output the file.

Comment: @colinross I wouldn't bother trying to parse HTML as XML. Especially since you don't even need all that .. just use `include` and output buffering.

Comment: @Frits: he isn't trying to just get the fully interpolated values, according to the question (as written) he thinks you can have variables held inside the value of another variable.

Comment: Probably because he doesn't know about include/output buffering. Writing HTML _in_ PHP is really not a good idea. Pick on or the other, or use a template.

Comment: @Frits, not trying to parse, just trying to convert, escape quotes, etc all in one go. Other variables are defined above my code, so I need to keep them in there rather than parse them. I realize writing HTML in PHP is terrible, but see my explanation above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that is a good idea. If only single variables are echoed it looks quite fine (although it's not an HTML file but a PHP file and your example `<? echo $anothervar>` is neither valid HTML nor PHP).

Look at PHPs [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) if you want to store the result in a variable:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
?>
<!-- your stuff here -->
<?php
    $output = ob_get_clean();
    // Do something with output
?>
```

Comment: `ob_get_clean` does `ob_get_contents` and `ob_end_clean` all in one go.

Comment: Yes, i changed that var up there, that was a formatting issue not originally in the file.

Comment: But question, is there any way to do this locally with some program to have it all in the PHP file itself, without relying on buffering?

Comment: Well the program to do this would be the PHP interpreter which you can also run on the command line. I think anything other way will be a big hassle.

Answer (score 3):

You could also use this ...

```
$your_var = <<<EOF

a bunch of html goes here

EOF;
```

Comment: HEREDOC doesn't allow variable interpolation iirc.

Comment: Then add an eval! Oh yea :D (seriously, don't)

Comment: That last comment confirms my feeling that any *give a man a fish* answer to this question will be an absolute hack and horrible coding practice. :-/

Comment: yeah but all his variables are in tags <?php ?>  so that should work with HEREDOC

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
include("myfile.html");
$var = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to read the HTML file as a variable, but put it within the PHP document, escaping it properly.

Comment: No he doesn't. He just wants the HTML with the PHP values substituted. My solution does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

[HTML To PHP Converter](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/HTML_converter/)

Answer (score 0):

please try this code

```
<?php $output='';
      $output.='<div class="section">';
      $output.='<h3>hey<? echo $anothervar ?></h3>';
      $output.='<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button" />';
     $output.='</div>';
     echo $output;

     ?>
```